# App script and Google Sheet - How to group 5 different values by code?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

Hi,
I want to group table values 5 difference value, If the values are equal, then do not count.
Using: App script and Google Sheet

Thanks.

Sample:

```
value   group5
a   1
b   1
c   1
d   1
v   1
d   2
v   2
b   2
c   2
d   0
s   2
c   3
v   3
f   3
a   3
c   0
v   0
b   3
c   4
d   4
v   4
```

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question and `I want to group table values 5 difference value, If the values are equal, then do not count.`, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. I apologize for this. What are the sample image and the sample values? In order to correctly understand about your current issue and your goal, can you provide your current script and the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 0):

```
function groupfunc() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const osh= ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  let obj = {pA:[]};
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {
      obj[r[1]] = [];
      obj[r[1]].push(r[0]);
      obj.pA.push(r[1]);
    } else {
      obj[r[1]].push(r[0]);
    }
  });
  let oA=[['Group','Values']];
  obj.pA.forEach((p,i)=>{
    oA.push([p,obj[p].join(',')]);
  });
  osh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
  osh.getRange(2,1,osh.getLastRow()-1,oA[0].length).sort({column:1,ascending: true})
}
```

Data Sheet1:

| value | group5 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 1 |
| d | 1 |
| v | 1 |
| d | 2 |
| v | 2 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 2 |
| d | 0 |
| s | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| v | 3 |
| f | 3 |
| a | 3 |
| c | 0 |
| v | 0 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 4 |
| d | 4 |
| v | 4 |

Output Sheet2:

| Group | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | d,c,v |
| 1 | a,b,c,d,v |
| 2 | d,v,b,c,s |
| 3 | c,v,f,a,b |
| 4 | c,d,v |